# Finding the number of leads a sales person owns

Tags: mysql, sql

Heres is an example of my schema:

```
|--------------------------|
|       **Lead**           |
|--------------------------|
|          Id              |
|        LeadId            |
|        OwnerId           |
|   ConvertedAccountId     |
|   ConvertedContactId     |
|  ConvertedOpportunityId  |
|       CampaignId         |
|       RecordTypeId       |
|--------------------------|
```

How can I find how many leads each sales person owns?

Comment: What's the relation between leads and sales person?

Comment: @AjayGupta The OwnerId represents the sales person who owns the lead

Comment: What have you tried so far????  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Eric Well i'm brand new to sql (and coding in general) and I understand that all that needs to be done is count the unique LeadId's for each OwnerId. I tried using if else cases and had little success as I couldn't figure out how to check a condition under a variable in sql.

Comment: @KaranVohra "I tried using if else cases".  Where's your query???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select OwnerId, count(*) from Lead group by OwnerId
```

Comment: Well, here in the above query `group by` arranges the rows with same `OwnerId` into a group. You can google `group by` for more examples.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!